# Details: How Flink achieves exactly-once mechanism?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

From a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54435309/about-flink-exactly-once-feature), it seems Flink achieves exactly-once by

> After a successful pre-commit, the commit must be guaranteed to
>   eventually succeed

I think "a successful pre-commit" is achieved by Flink Task Manager; and the "eventual succeed" is achieved by the Flink sink.

1. How Flink sink node achieves the "eventual succeed"?
2. Does this exactly-once mechanism have anything to do with checkpoint?

Answer (score 2):

Flink's two-phase commit sinks typically couple their actions with the checkpointing mechanism in the following way:

- *onSnapshot*: Flush all records and pre-commit
- *onCheckpointComplete*: Commit pending transactions and publish data
- *onRecovery*: Check and commit any pending transactions

Note that it is possible for data to be lost if the external system times out pending transactions that would be committed during the *onRecovery* phase.

You can learn more about this in [An Overview of End-to-End Exactly-Once Processing in Apache Flink (with Apache Kafka, too!)](https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/03/01/end-to-end-exactly-once-apache-flink.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Could you give me some reading pointers for the two-phase commit sinks and checkpointing mechanism as mentioned above?

Comment: https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/03/01/end-to-end-exactly-once-apache-flink.html