# What exactly happens if checkpointed data cannot be committed?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm reading into the details of Flink's checkpointing mechanism right now and by now, I think I have a really good overview about how everything is tied together but one last issue strikes me here.
It's about how checkpoints and commits interact with each other in the *ExactlyOnce* context, because I have the feeling that there's still potential for data loss/duplicate records. Mainly I was thinking about potential failures of the `commit` message or its callback, when I stumbled upon this paragraph in the Flink Blog:

> After a successful pre-commit, the commit must be guaranteed to eventually succeed – both our operators and our external system need to make this guarantee. If a commit fails (for example, due to an intermittent network issue), the entire Flink application fails, restarts according to the user’s restart strategy, and there is another commit attempt. This process is critical because if the commit does not eventually succeed, data loss occurs.

Up until this point, I still had the impression that checkpoints would have to be acknowledged by the sink commit *first*, before they would be viewed as "valid". But [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54435309/about-flink-exactly-once-feature), once all operators are ready to actually commit, the checkpoint starts to exist and from that point on, the sink has to guarantee the commit can be done to ensure no data being lost. **What exactly happens if my commit can never be done, e.g. if my Kafka sink is down for a longer period of time?** Does this mean if the defined retries run out eventually, the checkpointed state will just be [treated as the correct state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59450744/details-how-flink-achieves-exactly-once-mechanism) or will Flink only be able to resume the job once this specific commit was able to be done and thus be stuck until broker is available again?

And what if the callback of the `commit` is lost somehow, will this be resolved in the next retry attempt or since the transaction is "done" now, the producer will not be able to commit and we enter this loop of repeated retries? (more of a Kafka question probably)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For committing the side effects (so things like external state, vide Kafka transactions), Flink is using [two phase commit protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol).

Let's say we are performing checkpoint 42. First pre-commit requests are issued. If all participants (parallel subtasks/operators) successfully acknowledged the pre-commit, `JobManager`/`CheckpointCoordinator` will start sending out commit requests.

The thing is, if failure happens at this point of time, there is no way going back. If either some commit fails or there is some other unrelated failure, job will be restarted from the checkpoint 42 and Flink will re-attempt to commit the pending/pre-committed transactions. If failure happens again, rinse and repeat according to [your selected restart strategy](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/task_failure_recovery.html#restart-strategies). If you want to avoid data loss, commit attempts must eventually succeed. There is simply no other way. We can not revert those transactions, as once some commit request were issued, some transactions might have already been committed, so we can not rollback only portion of them (otherwise we would have data duplication problem).

Comment: So consider the case where the sink is down long enough that the selected retry strategy has definitively failed the job without the transaction associated with checkpoint 42 having been successfully committed. At that point checkpoint 42 assumes things about the sink that aren't true, and I do have data loss. Correct?

Comment: Yes @DavidAnderson. You need to do a stop with savepoint if you want to make sure, that transactions are committed (external side effects are materialised) without running  cluster.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks for elaborating on my question, that's exactly the detail I wanted to know about. So it's not like a Flink job will be unable to start from that checkpoint, rather "just" data loss is going to happen and the job will be able to start without errors (when restarted manually). Additional thought I had just now: will the checkpoint from this scenario even be existent, if I do not explicitly configure for retain? By default, checkpoints have a certain lifecycle, but are they only cleared, when a job enters "Canceled" or also when it enters "Failed" state? I assume first

Comment: @kopaka Even if you haven't configured the checkpoints to be retained on cancellation, a checkpoint will exist if one is needed: i.e., if the job fails. By default checkpoints are managed automatically, and are cleared up only when they can no longer be needed for failure recovery. Once a job has been stopped or cancelled, it can no longer fail.

Comment: So only manual cancellation will clear the checkpoints, good to know. Another question that fits this scope: How about savepoints? I assume they work similarly in regards of consistency (wait until all operators ready for pre-commit and then they trigger commit). But as they are manually created, checkpoints may be triggered after, which do hold a newer state of the application. Resuming from a savepoint instead of the latest checkpoint would lead to duplicates in the sink, right? This would be expected behaviour when creating savepoints without cancellation of the job, just want to make sure.

Comment: Yes @kopaka. Under the hood savepoints and checkpoints are working almost exactly the same way. The major difference is that we do not claim to support upgrades of Flink or jobs (like adding new operator) from savepoints. And yes, resuming from an earlier savepoint would lead to data duplication.